# How to set up OpenVPN server on Debian to route VPN traffic to the Internet

Tags: debian, iptables, openvpn, nat

I am setting up an OpenVPN server on Debian.

I have the server configured, and clients can connect - they are assigned IP addresses in the 10.11.22.0/24 range.

I have the following in my server.conf file:

```
client-to-client
status /var/log/openvpn-status.log
verb 3

server 10.11.22.0 255.255.255.0

# This ensures Internet-bound traffic to-from clients can pass through the VPN
push "redirect-gateway def1"
push "dhcp-option DNS (my DNS address)"
```

I have ip forwarding on (set in `/etc/sysctl.conf`)

I think I need to add a NAT rule to iptables, probably of the form

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.11.22.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

(corrections welcome!)

My question is, where should this rule go, to make it persistent (to survive reboots)?

I guess, in an ideal world, the rule would be added when the VPN server comes up, and removed when it goes down, but the server is set to auto-start in systemctl anyway, so it probably doesn't matter.

I just want to do it in the right place, so another sysadmin isn't surprised, and can find it.

Comment: Notice that `10.11.22.0/32` range contains exactly one IP address: `10.11.22.0`. Your actual OpenVPN config seems to specify `10.11.22.0/24` which makes much more sense.

Comment: Good spot, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, firewall should be independent from the VPN. In Debian it could be managed (saved and restored) using `netfilter-persistent` and `iptables-persistent` packages (both of them are required).

However, it is possible to run any commands when OpenVPN server starts up or shuts down, for which it has a scripting interface. In this case, don't use `netfilter-persistent` & `iptables-persistent` otherwise your firewall may bloat (consider the following scenario: script added a rule, then firewall is saved, then script removes the rule, reboot — firewall loaded *saved* state with the rule, then script runs and adds *another* rule; after some repeats you see several same rules in the firewall).

First, add to OpenVPN config:

```
script-security 2
up /etc/openvpn/add-rule.sh
down sudo /etc/openvpn/remove-rule.sh
```

`script-security` is needed for it to run scripts at all.

It is very likely you have non-root `user` and/or `group` in the server config (which is good!) so your `down` script will execute with that user/group privileges. Therefore you need to gain privileges again to be able to remove the rule. Create a file `/etc/sudoers.d/openvpn-remove-rule` that contains the following line which will enable this user to run the said command:

```
<user> ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /etc/openvpn/remove-rule.sh
```

(replace `<user>` with whatever user is set in the OpenVPN config, probably `nobody`). Then `chmod 0400 /etc/sudoers.d/openvpn-remove-rule` otherwise sudo will refuse to load it.

Explanation [why we need a script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/279125/allow-user-to-run-a-command-with-arguments-which-contains-spaces) and not just put an iptables command call via sudo directly into OpenVPN config. In short: security.

On the contrary, `up` command runs before dropping root privileges, but for consistency I suggest to use script for it too.

Contents of those scripts are obvious, just put your iptables commands that need to be run on server startup and shutdown. (In principle, you can use any commands there, not just iptables.) Make both scripts executable.

Read `man openvpn` for reference of its scripting interface.

Comment: We have **a lot** of docker containers on the server, each of which adds loads of iptables rules. I suspect iptables-persistent wouldn't be appropriate (but happy to be told otherwise).

Comment: That's pretty reasonable. If you wrote that in the question, I'd not even bother to suggest, but there were not a single word about Docker,

Comment: No criticism was intended - just checking with you that my approach was reasonable. It's always difficult to be sure what information is relevant to a question. But thanks very, very much for your excellent and informative answer.